# JSR223 Sampler SSL certificate issues

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jsr223

I have the following code in JSR223 Sampler and I get SSL certificate error. Is there any way to do disable?

Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;


List<String> sendRequest(String url, String method, String body) {


    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .build();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");


    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create(method)
            .setConfig(requestConfig)
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .setEntity(entity)
            .build();

   String req = "REQUEST:" + "\n" + request.getRequestLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
            request.getAllHeaders() + "\n" + EntityUtils.toString(entity) + "\n";


    HttpClientBuilder.create().build().withCloseable {httpClient ->

        httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable {response ->

            String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n" + response.getStatusLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
                    response.getAllHeaders() + "\n" +
                    (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

            System.out.println(req + "\n"  + res );

            return Arrays.asList(req, res);
        }
    }
}

List test1 = sendRequest("https://testserver.com","POST", "");
log.info(Arrays.toString(test1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler instead, as per documentation:

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers

---

However if you're doing something very special and need to do the same in Groovy - here is example solution:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

List<String> sendRequest(String url, String method, String body) {


    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .build();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");


    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create(method)
            .setConfig(requestConfig)
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .setEntity(entity)
            .build();

    String req = "REQUEST:" + "\n" + request.getRequestLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
            request.getAllHeaders() + "\n" + EntityUtils.toString(entity) + "\n";

    def builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    });
    def trustAllFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), new NoopHostnameVerifier());

    HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(trustAllFactory).build().withCloseable { httpClient ->

        httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable { response ->

            String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n" + response.getStatusLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
                    response.getAllHeaders() + "\n" +
                    (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

            System.out.println(req + "\n" + res);

            return Arrays.asList(req, res);
        }
    }
}

List test1 = sendRequest("https://testserver.com", "POST", "");
println(Arrays.toString(test1));
```

More information:

- [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I needed to use JSR223Sampler to send Multipart form-data, changing the image on the fly. I couldn't acheive this via HTTPSamplerProxy